# Can someone help me explain the concept of bank select register?

Tags: c, assembly, binary, microcontroller

Can someone please help me explain the concept of bank select registers, with regards to microcontrollers? I am using the PIC18F and am reading up and learning about data movement in class. 
The concept of bank select register and access bank is still new and confusing to me. (especially access bank, when i do a google search all I see is stuff about regular money banks =[ )

Examples of things I read which is confusing:

Instruction: CLRF F,a  ==========> Clear data register F to zero. F is located in access bank if a = 0 and F is located in the bank specified by BSR if a = 1

Instruction MOVWF F,a  =========> Move data from WREG into data register F. F is located in access bank if a = 0 and in the bank specified  by BSR if a = 1.

^I understand the first parts about WREG etc..., but not really comprehending the access banks and BSR. Much appreciated if anyone knew any resources or anything to help out :)

Comment: What **specifically** in the datasheet/reference manual did you not understand? The PIC documentation is quite clear about this.

Comment: The concept? Generally: suppose the micro can address 64k bytes but you want it to have 128k bytes of RAM. That cannot be done directly, but could be solved by having 8 banks of 16k bytes each, and a paging register to select which of the 8 banks is assessible. Which ever memory bank is selected appears at the same place in the memory map, and only one page can be read/written at a time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The need for banks comes from PIC's ability to address 12-bit address space, while a single-byte address fits only eight bits. Hence, you need to set the upper four bits into Bank Select Register (BSR).

This addressing scheme quickly becomes a burden, because instructions for switching between banks start littering the text of an assembly program, which is not particularly easy to read, and because these instructions take valuable space. In order to alleviate this problem, PIC architecture introduced so-called *access bank*.

Access bank contains a portion of special address space of 0..128 special bytes spread across BANK 0, plus some registers from the last bank. PIC gives you an ability to access these locations without switching banks, simply by setting `a` to zero. Careful planning of your memory usage lets you save a good deal of program memory by placing commonly accessed data in the access registers, and using quick access addressing mode.

See this [Q&A](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/30773/11330) for additional information on the subject.

Comment: Note that frequently the PIC18F executes in an extended mode which swaps out the fixed RAM in the access for memory indexed off of FSR2, allowing efficient access to variables on a local stack frame to ease C code generation. The I/O cells are still there though.